# jQueryUI draggable element loses containment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a little thumbnail that represents all the window. You can move `div#maquetaPant` and the window should to scroll at the same time you move the little square.

It's easier If you try:

http://www.noteboardapp.com/boarddemo

Drag the little square on the mini map on top right.

The code is here. If I put the function "dragMaqueta" in the stop event, then it works well. But I want it in the drag event to scroll the window at the same time of dragging the square. But if you try you'll see that doesn't work. It seems that `window.scrollTo(scrollX,scrollY)` moves the square outside the container.

```
    <div id="canvasDiv">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="125" height="100"></canvas>
        <div id="maquetaPant"></div>
    </div>

#maquetaPant
{
    position: absolute;
}

$("#maquetaPant").draggable({containment: '#canvasDiv',drag: dragMaqueta});

function dragMaqueta(evt,ui)
{
   var scrollX =  parseInt(ui.position.left / $('#canvasDiv').width() * $('.Postits').width());
   var scrollY =  parseInt(ui.position.top / $('#canvasDiv').height() * $('.Postits').height());
    window.scrollTo(scrollX,scrollY);
}
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: The drag event fires a lot, and there's a lot of other Javascript on the page - based on your saying that it works fine in the dragStop event - could it be a race condition? Try to "debounce" so that dragMaqueta only executes once at the same time, as a quick hack with a global flag that you set at the start of dragMaqueta, and unset at the end: `function dragMaqueta(evt, ui) { if (!flag) { flag = true; (...rest of dragMaqueta); flag = false; } }`

Comment: Thank you @UweB I understand whay you say but it doesn't work the flag solution. I tried too to add a timer and only execute the function every some number of miliseconds but the behavoir is the same. I think the problem is when I drag the position attribute of the #maquetaPant changes and the scroll moves the square outside.